# Not able to load Drupal site

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-theming

I have downloaded a new theme from Themeforest however when loading the site I m getting the below error. 
Even developer is confused about the error. 
I believe its more of drupal issue can anyone help?

```
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:\wamp\www\sites\all\modules\media\file_entity/file_entity.file_api.inc' (include_path='.;c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12\pear') in C:\wamp\www\sites\all\modules\media\file_entity\file_entity.module on line 13
```

Comment: Are you sure your PHP pear is locate at `c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12\pear` ? It seems wrong path - check your WAMP configuration.

Comment: C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12\pear this directory exists

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using relative path like

```
require_once("./file_entity.file_api.inc");
```

Before that you need to find out the getcwd() for getting the current working directory.'

then give relative path according to that.

OR

use below,

```
require_once(DRUPAL_ROOT . '/sites/all/modules/media/file_entity/file_entity.file_api.inc');
```

Comment: YOu mean modifying the file ? I m sorry can you please explain where shall i put this line?